# InApp Photo Editor ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, edit, photo, image-editor

Is there a easy way to edit a photo taken via the camera in my application?  I just want the user to take a photo in app→crop→save.  I just want the user to do this very simple task but I can't do it.  Is there an easy way to do this? I want it to be like the cinemagram that dosen't have the effects but instead cropping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `allowsEditing` property of [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and the user will get a chance to crop the photo after they take it. It's an easy class to use. Refer to the [Camera Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010400) for code samples and info.

Comment: I tried to use the allows editing but it goes back to the center when I want to crop the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Set your imagePicker.allowsEditing to Yes

```
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Then set up your delegate method..

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

if you want to save it to your Camera Roll add this after UIImage *image....:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: It always bounces back to the middle unless you zoom in a bit.